# Rotate an element on the corner with RaphaelJs like Photoshop

Tags: algorithm, transform, rotation, raphael

I would like to rotate an object like transform tool in PS.

I Try my best. And I am pretty close.

Here is a buggy VERSION .. because since I only pick up the Mouse coordinate and the difference.

There is a version with Jquery unfortunately it works only with IE and I would not even turn by pressing the  shift key. (Check the first link, there are a link in HMTL Part to the jquery tutorial)

http://jsfiddle.net/QmB4X/204/

And here is a version where I'm trying .. But unfortunately not figured out.

http://jsfiddle.net/QmB4X/201/

Would it be cool if you can just create a circular motion with that.

I do not understand the algorythm .. example how to get the current image angle.

Thank you in advance.

Only the Blue Box can be rotated .. if you click on the red square and small moves.

Answer (score -2):

I am looking for a Rafael solution similar to what is asked above too.

I also noticed that the blue box only rotates clock wise. I think we'll have to add logic to make it rotate counter clockwise too based on the drag direction by the user.

Cheers,
GJ

Comment: This is not an answer to the question